# How can use threading in for loop in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I want to use multitasking in a while loop and a for loop in python to make the code faster, I have 300 coins in 50 lists and all the lists in one list.

```
while True:
     for i in range(len(usdtLists)):
         Thread(target= stopping_volume, args= (usdtLists[i], i)).start()
```

but I always get this error:   unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'relativedelta'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Launching that many threads in parallel may be inefficient and cause errors. You should create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (or `ProcessPoolExecutor`) and submit work to it. For instance you can use the `.map(...)` method to execute the same function with different arguments from an iterator:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as e:
  e.map(stopping_volume, usdList, range(len(usdList)))
```